# Docker - Elasticsearch Container Unhealthy (even with OFFICIAL tuto)

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a docker compose file running Elasticsearch and my app.

The docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge


services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.1
    container_name: elasticsearch_dev
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl", "elasticsearch:9211/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 2
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9211:9200
    networks:
      - net

  #kibana:
  #  container_name: kibana_dev
  #  image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.0
  #  environment:
  #    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9211
  #  ports:
  #    - 5601:5601
  #  depends_on:
  #    - elasticsearch
  #  networks:
  #    - net

  engine:
    container_name: engine
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    env_file:
        - .env   
    ports:
      - 3010:3010
    depends_on: 
      elasticsearch: 
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - net

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
```

My problem :

```
ERROR: for engine  Container "49da392d9992" is unhealthy.
```

I'm running out of idea to understand that problem...

I'm quite surprised because, when i'm trying to run the "tuto" on the official Elasticsearch page :

[tuto](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)

it gives me a unhealthy error too...

If someone has a clue, I will owe him a debt...